# Openshift CPU Usage vs CPU request % vs CPU Limit %

Tags: resources, microservices, openshift, load-testing

I have dilemma in the understanding of the below terms wrt pod resource utilization in openshift.
I have executed the load test against a microservice and while measuring the CPU consumption of the pod. 
From the Observe tab of openshift, I could see the below readings:
[image]

I understand CPU request and CPU limit as the allocated resource. However during the load test execution, what does the values mentioned in CPU request % and CPU limit % signifies? 
 And how is CPU usage calculated.
 Appreciate if someone can explain this.
 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Request is purely for planning purposes. It is a kind of "wish list" for the container, and it is used to find the most suitable node. At the same time, Limit can be compared to a rigid contract - once we select a node for a container, it cannot go beyond the set limits. For more details, [see here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#requests-and-limits).
Percentage values - how much resources are used at the moment as a percentage of a particular limit. For example, in your example with Request - 0.025/0.75 = 3.33%, Openshift displays it as 3.27% :)

In Openshift cluster Kubelet publishes metrics using [Heapster](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install_config/cluster_metrics.html).